# Track a link on a page, but not a pageview in Google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have a several web pages with a graphic banner to be used in an iframe on affiliates website. But what is happening is that those iframe pages are bloating our pageviews in Google Analytics. I want to track the link of the banner, but not count the webpage as a page view.

I have a noindex and follow in the meta information, but I am taking that this is not enough because the pages are still being tracked as a pageviews.

Is there something that I am overlooking?

Any insight would be great!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you embedding your GA tracking code in your iFrame?  To begin with, I don't think you want to do this.  But if you want to track the number of clicks, and do this within Google Analytics, I presume you would have to make your link a Redirect and then create a custom event in the redirect.